# SFTP as a folder on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, sftp, webdav

Is there a program available for Vista, that allows me to set up a folder as an SFTP connection to a remote server?

The use case is to have a folder on my desktop, where I can drag/drop/edit files and have my remote location be updated automatically.

I've googled this to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: See also "Keep ftp folder sync’d with windows folder" at http://superuser.com/questions/48782/keep-ftp-folder-syncd-with-windows-folder

Comment: [win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) is decent, but doesn't automatically reconnect when the connection is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive/) will let you do this.  It has a 30-day trial, but requires a purchase ($39.95) after the 30 days.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

[**NetDrive**](http://www.netdrive.net/) is free for home use and fulfills all your requirements. See its review in [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/300997/mount-remote-file-systems-with-netdrive).
Features:

- Mounts remote storage as a local hard disk on your PC
- Data transfer by drag and drop files in windows explorer
- Able to run files (video, audio and any other .exe files)
- Mounts drive automatically when Windows starts.
- Operating System : Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 2003/2008 (32/64bit)

[image]

**Open Source alternative:**

[win-sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) is a new open-source project that mounts SSHFS/SFTP as a network drive :

> SSH(SFTP) filesystem made using Dokan and SSH.NET library. It allows you to mount remote computers via SFTP protocol like windows network drives.

**Commercial alternatives:**

For example, [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/index.html) ($59.95), reviewed [here](http://rbytes.net/software/webdrive-review/):

> WebDrive integrates FTP, WebDAV, SFTP
>   or FrontPage servers into the Windows
>   desktop by making your web server
>   appear as a network drive.

[image: image1]

Another option is [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows) ($39.95) :

> With ExpanDrive, you can securely
>   access any remote file server directly
>   from Explorer, or even the command
>   line. No need to open a separate SFTP
>   client just for file transfer.
>   ExpanDrive extends the way all
>   applications on your PC can access
>   data.

[image: image2]

Comment: "except for sftp" I think SFTP was kinda the whole point.

Comment: According to LifeHacker, NetDrive does SFTP: http://lifehacker.com/300997/mount-remote-file-systems-with-netdrive

Comment: Excellent news for the OP (but isn't mentioned on the netdrive website). I've therefore edited my answer.

Comment: I'm going to check this out after my trial of ExpanDrive expires.  Thanks!

Comment: NetDrive is not compatible with 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: I added one open source solution

Answer (score 6):

JFYI: we have made [SFTP Net Drive](http://nsoftware.com/netdrive/sftp) free application available. It lets you mount the remote SFTP folder as a local disk with a drive letter.

Comment: Haven't used it (I'm not on Windows), but looks nice.

Comment: I have been using this solution for several weeks now... it is exactly what I think a lot of people are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately Windows 7 does not remember my thumbnails for these drives, so it spends lots of time and bandwidth generating them every time I visit any folder.  Is there a way to fix this?  What effect do the "fixed" and "removable" options have?

Comment: There's no way to "fix" it because this is not a bug. Explorer reads thumbnails by design and so far nobody knows how to stop it from doing so. Network drive type should reduce the number of reads.

Comment: SFTP Net Drive has moved here: https://www.nsoftware.com/netdrive/sftp/

Comment: @EpicVoyage Thank you, I've updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

I thought FUSE would be helpful, but [the Windows section](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=OperatingSystems#Windows) claims:

> Is it really true that there are no FUSE port for Windows? If anyone knows of one add it to this list, please.

So, if anyone here knows about it: edit that page!

However, that very same Windows section does list other options, some of which [apparently](http://kelley.ca/wordpress/2008/05/23/fuse-for-windows/) "fall back to implementing a FUSE compatibility layer on top of FIFS which implements a SMB server to provide access to other filesystems". I doubt it's useful, but if all else fails then looking at that list might help. It seems that [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/docs/dokan-sshfs-readme/) might be a good FUSE-like alternative for Windows, especially for SSH/SFTP.

(And, when really taking things to extremes, one could even use DeleGate as a [FTP-to-SFTP gateway](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/ssh/), just in case one finds something that only supports FTP...)

Comment: There is a new open source project named "win-sshfs" that uses Dokan as backend. works pretty well for me: http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/ .. cannot add this as an answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

DirectNet Drive is free for home use.

http://directnet-drive.net/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaking it for FTPS (I always confuse the two), but I believe this capability is built into windows explorer.  Just open a folder window and type an ftp url (including secure items) into an address bar.  Something like this:

```
sftp://user:pass@ftpsite.example.com/
```

You should be able to make a normal windows folder shortcut to that location as well.  If you leave off the username and password it should prompt you.

Comment: I don't this this meets the Drag-and-Drop requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Found new app - RaiDrive! So far, the best!
https://www.raidrive.com/