# Mounting SSH/SFTP shares on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssh, mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SFTP as a folder on Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/55860/sftp-as-a-folder-on-Vista)

I'm fairly unfamiliar with Windows, especially Windows 7, but using it for a school project; essentially I have a directory accessible through SSH that I would want to mount in Windows 7 the same way you would do it through sshfs in Linux or OS X, but I don't know of any FUSE port for Windows 7. Does anyone know any easy way to accomplish this in Windows 7?

(Just a regular SFTP client like FileZilla would work, but I'd prefer not to have to manually transfer the file(s) over for compilation every time I make a change, so something that mounts it as a local volume is preferred.)

Comment: This has been discussed here already: http://superuser.com/questions/55860/sftp-as-a-folder-on-vista

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. The other question asks only about SFTP, this one asks about SSHFS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at [Dokan SSHFS](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-sshfs) for Windows. Dokan SSHFS is a program that mounts remote file systems using SSH. You will need to install the [MSVC 2005 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647) and the Dokan library available on the SSHFS download page.

Another solution is to use [MindTerm](http://www.appgate.com/index/products/mindterm/) along with [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) (both have free home versions):

> 1. Download and extract mindTerm
> 2. Run mindterm.jar (double click it if you can, otherwise in command
>      prompt type in java -jar mindterm.jar)
> 3. Type in the host you want to ssh into followed by the username and
>      password
> 4. In the menu click on Plugins>FTP To SFTP Bridge…
> 5. Type in 127.0.0.1 for the Listen address
> 6. Type in  21 for the Listen port
> 7. Select the Remote system type
> 8. Click Enable
> 9. Click Dismiss
> 10. Next we want to install NetDrive
> 11. Once netdrive is installed, open it up, and click New Site on the
>       bottom
> 12. Type in localhost (or whatever you want to call it) for the Site name
> 13. Type in localhost for the Site IP
> 14. Type in 21 for the Port
> 15. Select FTP for the Port
> 16. Select a Drive letter
> 17. Check Connect as anonymous
> 18. Click Save
> 19. Click Connect
> 20. Click the X to close the window (will minimize to system tray)
>
> There you have it! A SSH/SFTP
>   connection as a drive in Windows. I
>   have tested it in Windows Vista,
>   however it should work just fine in
>   Windows XP.

[Source](http://www.lalitkapoor.com/blog/2008/06/29/mount-ftp-or-sftp-as-a-drive-in-windows/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply John :) But do you happen to know anything about Dokan's Windows 7 compatibility? I'm a bit concerned about the fact that its last release was from way before Windows 7 was even released to manufacturing. Does anyone have any idea whether it still works?

Thanks!

Comment: Since 0.3.7 Vista 32 and x64 are supported ( http://dokan-dev.net/en/2008/08/20/dokan-library-037-released/ ) so I assume Windows 7 should work. Added another solution in case.

Comment: Unfortunately the Dokan installer won't even run on Windows 7, it automatically complains that it's not a recognized version of Windows :( I may give the NetDrive thing a try though, thanks!

Comment: Just for curiosity sake, have you tried running it in Vista compatibility mode?

Comment: Surprisingly, that worked like a charm :D (compatibility mode, that is)

Thanks a bunch, John!

Comment: Excellent! You're welcome :)

Comment: Just for an updated reference Netdrive can mount a SFTP by selecting FTP as the server type and going into the advanced setting and change SSL to SFTP using SSH2.

Comment: Is it possible to set the remote folder, when using netdrive on its own.

Comment: Just an update you can run the installer as is now. It will work on Windows 7 just fine.

Comment: FYI: it runs in Windows 8 if you install it with compatibility mode