# How to view images on FTP?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, image-viewer

Looking for a Windows 7 program or service to see my images on my FTP (small preview). 
With the possibility of removing not needed images.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) since version 4 was released for Windows a few days ago, but I'm pretty sure it has [such a preview feature](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/browser#QuickLook). Either way, it's my go-to FTP client - a *really* excellent program.

*Update:* the documentation says that it has a file preview feature (I know it does this on OS X using Quick Look) but I can't seem to find it in the Windows version.

Comment: I twice tried to install this program. Each time it was long something downloaded in about 15 minutes and then reported "Error while downloading .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile."

Comment: You need to install .NET 4. See [this page](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/faq#Windows). But, as per my edit, I can't find a way to actually show the preview on Windows.

Comment: Finally installed the program. Unfortunately, the program is not possible to create thumbnails of images:(

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with FTP. For any program to see the image (not just windows) it must download the entire image then render it. When you see thumbnails on a website or in windows there is a second scaled down copy hiding somewhere (you can just see the path on a normal web page if you view the source, for windows it is inside that thumbs.db (the finename stands for Thumbnail Database :) ))

Now there are a [lot](http://download.cnet.com/Mass-Downloader/3000-2071_4-10037598.html) of [programs](http://www.httrack.com/) that can spider your FTP and download all the images locally for you and you would be able to see thumbnail previews once it is downloaded, but nothing can do it without downloading the entire file first.

Comment: FTPVoyager and SmartFTP have thumbnail views.

Comment: @JohnnyW FTP Voyager and SmartFTP both fall under the category of the 2nd paragraph. They still need to download the entire file to generate the thumbnail.

Comment: I know. The OP doesn't state that that would be an issue for him. It's the easiest solution if you have to download the images.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an FTP client, you could [mount the server as a drive](https://superuser.com/questions/67551/mounting-ssh-sftp-shares-on-windows-7-closed). That should let you see thumbnails and navigate the server as you would a local disk. The full files will have to be downloaded for thumbnails to be generated, but they will be cached on the server so only downloaded once.

Or use a web-based file manager on the server like [PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/) instead, which supports thumbnails and other cool features. Thumbnails are created on the server.