# Chrome extension to edit your own web pages' live html directly in-browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, ftp, html, google-chrome-extensions

I'm curious.

I recently changed the way I've been editing my websites for years (via FTP client), to dropbox-like syncing a version of the public_html folder on the PC to the one on the FTP, with real-time automatic sync, using [GoodSync](https://superuser.com/a/412909/78017).

Now it's unbelievably easy to update my website, and just play around with my own personal zippy sandbox (that *I* can control) for testing web apps and scripts and services and stuff. I simply create and edit and delete the folder/files with my favourite native apps on windows, and the changes immediately take place on the website.

I've also been playing around with AutoHotKey to do amazing website tasks with mere presses on the keyboard in Windows - the only limitation I now deal with, is the 5-10 seconds it takes for the change to become live on the web. (it's pretty cool to strip the interface/workflow down to almost the bare infrastructure - the physical network, more or less.)

And now, I'm just curious. Now, I'm thinking outside the box - or RE-thinking how I do things, if you like. So I'm in Chrome, looking at my page, and I reckon I can even do better. I'm looking at my webpage I've been working on, and I want to be able to re-edit it even quicker.

Is there some AWESOME chrome plugin than can store FTP details of multiple web servers I own, detect when I'm on a page belonging to one of those webservers (via automatic domain matching against my stored ftp domains or manually setting ftp accounts for certain domains/wildcards in the extension settings), and will let me right-click on said page and have a menu item like 'edit', load up the page's html source as editable text, let me change whatever I need, then I hit 'save' and it reloads the updated page?

Now THAT.....would be awesome.

Also, the software would have to be local and browser native - not some web-based service popup window that has its own resources to load and slow me down - but a local piece of software in Chrome that plugs directly into my FTP like a breeze.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any plugin that lets you do everything you've said, but if you enter the developer mode in Chrome by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and it will give you a view of all the HTML, CSS, JS, and anything else that your browser loaded for the webpage. From there, you can dynamically modify pretty much all of it. This only modifies the cache, and it will not edit the website on the server. However, it is useful to at least test quick changes before actually logging in, updating the server-side code on the live site, and then reloading the webpage.

Comment: I know, thanks, but I'm looking for a live updating method here....

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, as far I know about editing web and using chrome together.
Use notepad++ and set your server details.
You can edit and changes will reflect on saving file.

Websites do need time to reload web contents, and 
plugins or extension also takes time to save data then respond to web-server data..

total time is notepad++ and web server response to the changes.
That's all. You got your idea.