# FileZilla - How to synchronize two-way (newest file wins)?

Tags: sync, filezilla

I use several computers to maintain a website. I want to reflect all changes both ways.

This is a very standard procedure, but I can't find how to do it with FileZilla.

Answer (score 17):

FileZilla does not support automatic file/folder synchronization:
https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/1591

All it can do is to highlight differences between local and remote folder.

See *View > Directory comparison*.

---

If you need automatic folder synchronization, you have to use a different FTP/SFTP client.

For example [WinSCP supports directory synchronization](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full):

[image]

For two-way synchronization, select *Both* option in *Direction/Target directory*:

[image]

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Again, thankyou I love WinSCP. It's an amazing utility and makes my live much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested this myself but found an interesting article abut synching with FileZilla using FTP [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/synchronize-filezilla-47982.html)

Cant help but feel it sounds overcomplicated so perhaps there is a simpler solution. Personally, I would test out some other services like [goodsync](http://www.goodsync.com) or [ftpbox.org](http://www.ftpbox.org). A similar question was asked [here in Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time) but answers suggest using WinSCP.

Since you asked specifically about using FileZilla, here you go:

---

1. Download the FileZilla FTP client and install it to your computer if you have not already done so (link in Resources).
2. Launch FileZilla, click the “File” menu and select “Site Manager.”
3. Enter the FTP server domain name for your website in the Host field. Some sites use the “www.domainname.com” format for FTP services, while others require the “ftp.domainname.com” format. If you are unsure of the format your site uses, refer to the welcome email message you received from your hosting company when you created the account for your domain name and website. The email should contain all the necessary FTP and login information you need to use FileZilla to upload and synchronize files.
4. Type the FTP username and password you received from the hosting company in the corresponding fields of the Site Manager window. Enter “21” in the Port field unless your hosting company requires that you use a non-standard FTP port. Again, refer to the welcome email from the hosting company for this information.
5. Click the “Quick Connect” button to log in to the remote Web server. Wait a few seconds while FileZilla negotiates login credentials and establishes a connection with the server. FileZilla then displays the folders in the root directory of the Web server. Double-click the “Home,” “Public_HTML,” “WWW” or other directory name that contains the files and folders for your website.
6. Scroll down to the folder you want to synchronize with your computer. Note the name of the folder, then click “Disconnect” on the toolbar and close FileZilla.
7. Open Windows Explorer, then double-click the “C:\” drive icon. Click the “New Folder” button in the Windows Explorer window, then rename the folder so that it exactly matches the folder you want to synchronize on the server. Close the Windows Explorer window.
8. Launch FileZilla again. Click "File" and "Site Manager," then select your FTP server from the list. Click the “Advanced” tab in the Site Manager window, then click the “Browse” button next to the “Default Local Directory” field. Navigate to the new folder you created in Windows Explorer, then click “Open.”
9. Ensure that the folder name in the “Default Remote Directory” field matches the one in the “Default Local Directory” field exactly. Since you closed the FileZilla application while browsing the folder you want to synchronize on the server, the default folder names should match. However, if the folder names do not match, just type the folder name from the “Default Local Directory” field (without the “C:\”) into the “Default Remote Directory” field.
10. Click and enable the “Use Synchronized Browsing” option on the Advance tab, then click the “Connect” button. After you connect and establish an FTP session with the server, FileZilla prompts you to synchronize the folders. Click the “Yes” button to download files from the server to the new folder you created on the hard drive of your local computer. After you perform the initial synchronization of the folders, FileZilla scans for changes every time you reconnect to the FTP server. If new files exist in either folder -- local or remote -- the application prompts you to synchronize the directories. If you click “Yes,” FileZilla uploads or downloads files to synchronize the folders as needed.

Comment: The last (and the crucial) step does not work. FileZilla does not support file/folder synchronization. The synchronized browsing does not do what the post claims. All it does it that it changes working folder in an opposite panel, when you change it in an active panel.

Comment: I bow to your superior knowledge and love WinSCP. Thankyou for making my life much more awesome

Comment: I use the current version in debian stretch (3.24) and the widely claimed synchronization (step 10 above) does not work. I wish the filezilla group would indicate on their website which version is required for the sync to work, otherwise it appears as a false claim to people using the last distro version.

Comment: "Synchronization" in Filezilla means that when you change directories in either local/remote window, the other location (remote/local) will also change directories, such that both panes display the contents of the "same" (equivalent) directory.  It is really "synchronized directory view".  This is not "synchronization" of files: it will not auto copy (missing/changed) files from one location to the other, which is what the OP was actually asking about. [FileZilla does not support sync](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=8146).  WinSCP and FTP Voyager do support sync.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=ftp-setup), which is Open-Source and (besides Windows) also runs on GNU/Linux and macOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).