# Any windows FTP client for normal users?

Tags: ftp

I am hopelessly looking for FTP client for my boss. Eg BFU. It have to look and behave like explorer. Including automatic reconnect on background and most importantly ability to open&edit file directly (by synchronizing it with local temporary copy in background) (there is absolutely no way how to teach my boss to copy the *.doc to local computer, edit and copy back)

I don't believe nothing like that exists.

I tried:

- Default explorer ftp:// - Doesn't support edit in place
- FTPDrive - doesn't support edit in place
- FTPx - Can "open from FTP", but won't synchronize it back after edits are made
- Filezilla - Yes, this client have the needed functionality, but is not simple to use. I tried to setup it with hiding most of the 'confusing' panels and prompts, but still not enough.

Comment: Not a direct solution, but maybe write a small background app or service, which synchronizes a local folder with the FTP server. So for your boss it looks and behaves like a normal local folder (because it is one).

Comment: The way I see it, you aren't looking for a FTP client. You are looking for an almost invisible synchronization tool which will require no input from your boss and will keep that file updated on your FTP server. From this viewpoint you can check this question : http://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time and its answers

Comment: If you don't like the native Windows Explorer, vote in feedback for its improvement: https://aka.ms/Fjpi0y

Answer (score 0):

You could just connect via Windows Explorer. You can make a shortcut on the desktop and let your boss remember or write down credentials. You can connect by making a shortcut point to (or typing it in explorer adress bar):

```
ftp://ftpsite.com/
```

EDIT:
If you don't want to copy the file, edit it and copy back you can take a look at this post on Serverfault:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows

or take a look at this program:

> http://ftpx.com/

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried native explorer client and (at least in Windows 7 64bit) it doesn't support "direct" opening and editing files, I have to manually copy it to local disk first. Which is the problem.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FileZilla a free FTP Solution.

```
https://filezilla-project.org
```

Comment: Thats a good one but not very user-friendly. If his boss cant copy a file, edit and copy it back i think it is not a good idea to use something like Filezilla. But it is a good program.