# Is there any way I can save files directly with "Save as" function to an ftp server?

Tags: ftp, plugins, save-as

I looking for a solution which give me an additional option to "Save as" menu in some way (it could be a plugin or a Windows shell command, it really doesn't matter).

**What I would like to achieve:**

1. When you right click for a link to you get a "Save as" drop down menu.
2. When you hover over this option, you get sub-menus like:

   - "Save as directly to my ftp server" - when you click this option, the file gets saved immediately to a preconfigured folder.
   - "Save as to a specific folder" - we need to look for folders on the server, and select where we want to save the file.

My operating system is Windows 10 x64 pro version

Comment: Nice edit, thanks for the corrections @DavidPostill!

Comment: What FTP software are you using?

Comment: At this time I using filezilla

Comment: The problem with this question is that it indirectly asks us to provide suggestions on software that could do this, but this is off-topic here.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, asking indirectly is OK.  It's off-topic to request a software recommendation, but a question can request a solution to a problem for which software recommendations are the answer.  In the former case, just mentioning a product is technically an answer and it attracts lists of products with no qualitative information.  Asking for a solution requires a solution, and just a product name isn't a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a menu option very likely requires some sort of hacking.

But your intention was probably just to have quick access to your FTP server, right?

If so, you may want to map it somewhere accessible. 
This can be accomplished in two ways:

> *Edit:* This answer included a non-working solution which was later deleted, and another solution was added instead based on comments. Therefore comments no longer make sense regarding the answer. Sorry.

### Connect your FTP server as a disk drive

Windows does not have this capability built in, but there are some third-party sofware to do the trick:

- [Swish](http://www.swish-sftp.org/) (SFTP only, freeware)
- [FtpUse](http://www.ferrobackup.com/map-ftp-as-disk.html) (freeware)
- [Webdrive](https://southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/) (paid)
- [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) (paid)
- [SFTP-Net-Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/) (paid)
- [FTPDrive](http://www.killprog.com/fdrve.html) (freeware, but very old and can cause BSODs)

Refer to program documentation on how to map your FTP server to a drive.

When saving, just save it to the new mapped drive as you normally would.

See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows) question for details

### Synchronise a local folder with FTP-server in background

This is just like dropbox, but instead of dropbox cloud your files go to your server. You just save your files to a normal folder on your local drive, and some software copies it to the FTP-server once in a while.

The upside of this method is that saving files is not as terribly slow as sending your files in real time.

The downside is that you need to ensure the files are actually synced before shutting down your computer or disconnecting from the network.

These programs should help you (you may need further help setting them up):

- [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) (free)
- [FTPBox](http://ftpbox.org/) (free)
- [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/) (paid)
- [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/) (paid)
- [Fling](http://www.nchsoftware.com/fling/index.html) (paid)

For more info see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time) question

Comment: I liked your option one, but the windows dosen't allow me to save file directly to ftp.
Why?

Comment: Looks like expanddrive is a working solution, thanks for the tipp, it's awsome

Comment: However, it's takes forver save anything

Comment: (Sorry for late reply) Yes, unfortunately there may be problems akin to what you described. What program's "save as" are you clicking to save to FTP? Also you may be interested in this: http://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time

Comment: I apologize, it appears that windows can open files directly from ftp, but not save them there for some reason. Thought it could do both. I should have at least tested it before posting but was too lazy to set up a server. Really sorry for the inconvinience. I edited the answer removing the non-working solution, added background synchronizationg instead.